# how to sort vector string array using cmp function

Tags: c++, string, sorting

This is my compare function

```
bool cmp(string* s1,string* s2)
{return(strlen(s1)>strlen(s2));}
```

This is my Vector array

```
vector<string>v(n);
```

This is my sort function

```
sort(v.begin(),v.end(),cmp);
```

Where did I went wrong

Comment: Add the language tag please

Comment: Surely you are getting a warning when you pass a `string*` to `strlen`?  That's not what `strlen` accepts.

Answer (score 2):

> Where did I went wrong

Comparison function [should have](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) the signature similar to the following:

```
 bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
```

Therefore your comparison function could look like this:

```
bool cmp(std::string const& s1, std::string const& s2)
{
    return s1.length() > s2.length();
}
```

> it worked could please specify reason why it worked

It works because `std::sort` will take 2 vector elements and send them to the comparison function on each turn. The vector consists of `std::string`s, you could choose to pass them by value or reference or `const` reference but you cannot pass pointers like you tried (for that you would need `std::vector<std::string *>`, a bit pointless tbh)

Comment: it worked could u please specify reason why it worked,why it requires const type

Comment: Because this is the function signature [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) expect.

Comment: @NavneetHingankar added to the answer

Comment: @NavneetHingankar `bool cmp(string a, string b)` would've worked as well. Const references in this care are just for performance.